# Haskell usage of data type

Tags: haskell

I am reading [making our own types and typeclasses](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) in learn you a haskell.

In section [Algebraic data types intro](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#algebraic-data-types) I notice:

```
data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)  
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point deriving (Show)

surface :: Shape -> Float
surface (Rectangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2)) = abs (x2 - x1) * abs (y2 - y1)
```

In `surface (Rectangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2))`, we indicate the parameters for Rectangle are of type Point.

However, in section [Recursive data structures](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#recursive-data-structures):

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
singleton :: a -> Tree a  
singleton x = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree  

treeInsert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a  
treeInsert x EmptyTree = singleton x  
treeInsert x (Node a left right)   
    | x == a = Node x left right  
    | x < a  = Node a (treeInsert x left) right  
    | x > a  = Node a left (treeInsert x right)
```

We don't indicate `left`'s and `right`'s data types are `Tree a` in `treeInsert x (Node a left right)`. How does the compiler know their type?

Comment: From the definition of the `Tree a` data type, specifically the `Node` constructor: `Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)`.

Comment: The compiler knows their type because you declare `data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)`. Hence `left` and `right` always have to be of type `Tree a` (for whatever `a` is - in this case `a` is an instance of `Ord`). In the first example the `Point x1 y1` and `Point x2 y2` is only used for pattern matching. The compiler doesn't use it for type inference.

Comment: The compiler knows the types from the type signatures (the parts with `::`). You should go back and read the Pattern Matching section in chapter 4.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have a better understanding now. I apologize that I can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you have a misconception here:

> In `surface (Rectangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2))`, we indicate the parameters for Rectangle are of type `Point`.

This does indicate that the parameters are of type point, but perhaps not in the way that you think. The "`Point`" in `Point x1 y1` is not a type -- it's a constructor which happens to be named the same way as the type it constructs. If we declared `Point` as

```
data Point = MakePoint Float Float
```

then you would say

```
surface (Rectangle (MakePoint x1 y1) (MakePoint x2 y2))
```

For clarity, I will continue using `MakePoint` for the constructor and `Point` for the type.  It is legal Haskell to name these the same because the compiler can always tell from context, but humans sometimes have more trouble.

Within the context

```
surface (Rectangle (MakePoint x1 y1) (MakePoint x2 y2)) = ...
```

we know that the subexpression `MakePoint x1 y1` has type `Point` from *two* different places.  One is that the constructor `Rectangle` has type

```
Rectangle :: Point -> Point -> Shape
```

so we know that both of its arguments must be points (this is *outside-in* type inference, where we get the type of something from the context in which it's used); and the other is that the constructor `MakePoint` has type

```
MakePoint :: Float -> Float -> Point
```

so we know that `MakePoint x1 y1` represents a value of type `Point` (this is *inside-out* type inference, where we get the type of an expression from its components).  The compiler, in a way, uses both of these approaches and makes sure that they match.

However, sometimes one or the other of these kinds of information is lacking, for example `x1` in our example.  We have no inside-out information about `x1` (well, we would if we looked at the right hand side of the equation, which the compiler also does, but let's ignore that for now), all we have is that the arguments to the `MakePoint` constructor must be `Float`s, so we know that `x1` must be a `Float`.  This is valid and inferred by the compiler; there is no need to state it explicitly.

In the `Tree` example there is more confusing naming going on (which, once you get this, ceases to be confusing and begins being helpful, but it's good to draw a clear distinction at the start), so I'm going to rename the first argument of `Node` to from `a` to `v`:

```
treeInsert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a  
treeInsert x EmptyTree = singleton x  
treeInsert x (Node v left right)   
    | x == v = Node x left right  
    | x < v  = Node v (treeInsert x left) right  
    | x > v  = Node v left (treeInsert x right)
```

The same thing is happening with `left` and `right` as was with `x1` above: there is no inside-out structure to use, but we know that the `Node` constructor takes an `a` and two `Tree a`s, so `v` *must* be of type `a`, and `left` and `right` *must* be of type `Tree a`.  The compiler deduces this from the context.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Feel the second is a variable and the first is an object creation in Java.

Answer (score 2):

> In surface `(Rectangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2))`, we indicate the parameters for Rectangle are of type Point.

No.  This is your misconception.  The compiler knows the type of `Rectangle`'s arguments because of the data declaration:

```
data ... | Rectangle Point Point
```

In the code you were referencing:

```
surface (Rectangle (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2))
```

That is called a pattern match.  Surface takes a rectangle, which we pattern match in order to bind variable names to the parameters.  We also pattern match on each parameter to gain access to the sub-parameters and bind the variable names `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2`.